# How to create a DLL library from sourcecode.c and then use it with C#

Tags: c#, c++, c

i had two source file in my vs2010 ,sample.c and q.lib that call functions from a q.dll, all of this is a sample code.
i want to make from this code a dll and export one void function that i can call from my c# program.
i try to warp this function with

```
extern "c" 
{
   __declspec(dllexport) void D()
   {
      //dosome
   }
}
```

but doesn't work with .c but only with .cpp file ,and when i change it to sample.cpp i got an errors on convertion or someting like that.
What can i do ?
Thanks...

---

i try to do P/Invoke but i can do that only if i expose the function that i call from the c# with this earlyer code:
in the .c file

```
    extern "c" 
{
   __declspec(dllexport) void D()
   {
      //dosome
   }
}
```

and like i said "but doesn't work with .c but only with .cpp file ,and when i change it to sample.cpp i got an errors on convertion or someting like that" - the c code is very complicated and i dont want to Touch all the code but warp one function that use other functions in the complicated c code and call only to it from my c# code.
i used this tutorial to learn the P/Invoke facility:
[tutorial to learn the P/Invoke facility][1]
[1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w
but like i said it's work only with .cpp file but all my code is in .c file!!!
and this - extern "c" doesn't work in .c code.
help me to understand what can i do instead?

Comment: Could you develop your point further? I did not really understand the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extern "c" is c++ specific, as it tells the complier to export the function "like in c", so you don't need that in c.

you can do something like this, if you want it to compile with both c, and c++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) void D()
{
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you also need to tell VS to build a dll, and not an executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call functions in native DLLs from C# directly, but you can use them through a facility called P/Invoke. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Another option would be to write your wrapper in C++/CLI. C++/CLI is pretty much the standard way for allowing .Net code to wrap and consume native stuff.

Lastly, you could also use P/Invoke to call q.dll functions from C# instead of having a wrapper at all.